# WebJob Crontab schedule running at the top of the hour and every 15 min thereafter

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm trying to come up with a schedule for my Azure WebJob in crontab format that will run every 15 minutes but exactly at h:00, h:15, h:30 and h:45.

The one that I'm using for my web job right now is:

```
{ "schedule": "0 0/15 * * * *" }
```

But this doesn't make it run exactly at the top of the hour then every 15 minutes thereafter.

I want the job to keep running -- no end date/time. However, when I launch the webjob, it should not start running until it's h:00, h:15, h:30 or h:45 -- whichever happens to be next. For example, if I deploy my webJob at 8:37 AM, the first run should be at 8:45 AM AND it should then keep running every 15 minutes after that.

I'd appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: That schedule looks correct - what interval is your job running on? What's the problem?

Comment: My solution makes the job run every 15 minutes but the job doesn't run exactly at those times I mentioned in my question. For example, if I deploy my webJob to Azure at 9:03 AM, it will run at 9:03 AM. Then the next one will be at 9:18 AM. What I want is: if I deploy the job at 9:03 AM, the first run should be at 9:15 AM, then 9:30, then 9:45, then 10 AM, and so on.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. If it is, please log a bug on the public issues list here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues. The computation we do internally to compute the next timer interval should result in the schedule you expect. How are you determining the schedule is off - via the execution entries in the portal, or your own logging code?

Comment: I investigated more and have been able to repro this. I've created an issue in our repo here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1834. We'll get this fixed soon, and when the update deploys to Azure your job will run as expected.

Comment: On further investigation, I actually can't repro this. Can you please give me some exact steps I can follow to see the behavior you're seeing? I've tried various combinations of schedule changes/updates but it's working correctly for me. Please add any further notes on this to the issue here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1834. Once we resolve, I'll post back to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*/15` for minutes:

```
0 */15 * * * *
```

Comment: Azure WebJobs uses the expanded 6 field CRON format which includes seconds. So his original expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37847664/4167200)

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
second         0-59
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

So for you :

```
{ "schedule": "0 0,15,30,45 * * * *" }
```