# Azure WebJob not accepting a valid(?) CRON expression

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs, cronexpression

I used [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru/) to create a very simple CRON expression with the desired behavior to execute every day at 3:15 (AM) and this is the result: `15 3 * * *`

[image: Crontab.guru]

Unfortunately for me, in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) this does not work, but if I add a leading `0` to my expression as such, `0 15 3 * * *`, Azure will accept it, while `crontab.guru` will tell me it is wrong. The specification according to `crontab.guru` is: *minute hour date month weekday*.

[image: Azure does not accept my CRON expression]

[image: Azure accepts the expression with a leading zero]

The questions..

- From where comes the discrepancy?
- Is it Microsoft that in their traditional ways have a proprietary
  implementation with a leading zero?
- If the standard is *minute hour date month weekday*, what does the
  leading zero describe?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:

- [Create a scheduled WebJob using a <strike>CRON</strike> NCRONTAB expression](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON)
- [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions)

> The NCRONTAB expression is composed of 6 fields: {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}. A CRON expression has only 5, without the seconds.

So the first 0 describes the seconds.

```
*    *    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or    use names)
│    │    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    |    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
└────────────────────────────── second(0 - 59)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that it was seconds after a while, but why does it differ from place to place? Are there different standards? Transitional/Strict ? :)

Comment: sorry Marcus I don't really know, hopefully someone from the Microsoft team will add a comment ^^

Comment: i have created a webjob recently but it is not triggering automatically even setting correctly the CRON expression, i have also tried creating a settings.job file. What should i do to make it work?

Comment: Can you create a new question and post your code please ?

Comment: Yes there are different standards. See for instance another cronmaker that assumes the seconds is the first: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Use this one which follows the same standarts as in webjobs: http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: This page has better documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions

Comment: The second docs page linked has been recently updated (my PR was accepted, yay) to specifically state that these are 6 part NCRONTAB expressions and not the usual 5 part CRON expressions. I've asked for the first link to be corrected in the same way. If the snippet in your answer was from one of those two pages, you may want to update it to match any docs updates.